# How to add TTF font to html2pdf PHP program

Tags: php, truetype, html2pdf

I'm trying to use HTML2PDF 4.03 with this code:

```
<?php
$content = "..."; # my HTML code
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en', true, 'utf-8', array(15,20,15,20) );
# here I'm trying to add my arial.ttf
$html2pdf->pdf->AddTTFFont('arial.ttf');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
?>
```

Now the program die with this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method HTML2PDF_myPdf::AddTTFFont()
```

How can I add TTF font to my PDF file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have managed to add 1 custom font to my setup using the following method.

First convert the .ttf file to 3 separate files (.php .z and .ufm) using the following
[font converter](http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf)
 Place the 3 files that are generated by this system into the fonts folder in TCPDF.

Now you can set the default font for your PDF using the following command

```
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont("the_name_you_called_your_font");
```

This was fairly simple to get working, I am having issues using 2 seperate fonts though via this method. I'll figure it out though

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the selected answer (by o11y_75) when you convert your fonts, you need to use a specific name to include also the bold and italic variants.
That way, you only add one font definition like this

```
$html2pdf->AddFont('opensans', 'normal', 'opensans.php');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('opensans');
```

When you convert the fonts, name them, for example, like these:

```
default: opensans
bold: opensansb
italic: opensansi
bold italic: opensansbi
```

notice that behind the original name, you add b, i and bi on each case.
I have found no documentation on this issue, but I followed the nomenclature found on the fonts that already came with TCPDF and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple fonts, just use :

```
$html2pdf->addFont('opensansregular', '', 'opensansregular');
$html2pdf->addFont('opensansbold', '', 'opensansbold');
```

I would suggest that you don't use special chars with the font converter specified above.

Then in your CSS simply type :

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
* {
    font-family: opensansregular;
}
h1, h2, h3, strong {
    font-family: opensansbold;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. I have two font in my tcpdf/fonts folder. Both work when I add them as default. Let's say: `$html2pdf->setDefaultFont("francoisone");`. But when I try this: `$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('OpenSans'); $html2pdf->addFont('francoisone', '', 'francoisone');`, I can't use `font-family: francoisone;` in my css. Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Yes, I convertet `FrancoisOne.ttf`to `francoisone.afm, francoisone.php, francoisone.z`. And it works as DefaultFont. But not as addFont, when called via CSS `h1, h2, h3, h4 {font-family: francoisone;}`

Answer (score 0):

HTML2PDF works internally with TCPDF.
TCPDF has its own object since version 6.2.6 to create the fonts needed for HTML2PDF: `TCPDF_FONTS`

I have solved this as follows:
I searched for TCPDF in the vendor directory and found the Fonts directory there.
Then I created my own separate PDF script and used it once to create the necessary font files from the ttf.

```
usage: $fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/arialuni/arialuni.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337995/2320007