# How to add fonts in HTML2PDF?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF in Laravel 5.1 and I need to add two fonts. I've tried searching for answers but they don't work for me whenever I try them.

I have tried the following (based on searches):

- Go to http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ to generate .php and .zip files of my fonts
- I found a thread that said to put the files in `html2pdf\_tcpdf_5.0.002\fonts\` because it's the default directory for fonts in FPDF. I went to `vendor\spipu\html2pdf` to look for such directory but found nothing. So I just placed the generated files in `public\fonts` as well as the .ttf files.
- I also added the following to my code:

  `$cambria_path = base_path() . '\public\fonts\cambria.php';
  $html2pdf->addFont('cambria', '', $cambria_path);`

  However, this does not work. This is the error that shows up: `TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: cambria`
- I also tried this one:

  `$cambria_path = base_path() . '\public\fonts\cambria.ttf';
  $cambria = $html2pdf->pdf->addTTFfont($cambria_path, 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);`

  but it says `Call to undefined method HTML2PDF_myPdf::addTTFfont()`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I add at least one font (it would be better if I can add at least two though)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a webfont version?

Comment: @ceejayoz I haven't tried it. Is it much easier if I do that? I need to add Calibri (at least) to my pdf.

Comment: I can't promise it's easier nor that it's supported. Might be worth a shot if you don't make any headway on the font loading though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for you, but you could try http://stackoverflow.com/a/29618412/1739852

Answer (score 0):

In your second try I think you are calling incorrectly:

**INCORRECT:**

```
$html2pdf->pdf->addTTFfont
```

That's why they saying undefined method.

**CORRECT:**

```
$html2pdf->addFont('fontname', 'fontname.php')
```